Encrypt files including their file names in an Ansible repo
I have an public Ansible repository with some templates files I need to hide/encrypt. I need not only to encrypt their content, but also their file names.
I have been trying ansible-vault and git-crypt but it seems none of them have any option to encrypt the file names.
I was thinking about compressing/archiving the files in archive(s) with an obfuscated name(s), before encrypting the archive(s), but that overcomplicates the workflow.
Is there any other solution or recommended way I could use to do so?

"Is there any other solution or recommended way I could use to do so?", maybe Custom Filter Plugin, like b64encode, b64decode.

Given the list of files, for example,
  files: [foo, bar, baz]

Create the obfuscated files
    - file:
        state: touch
        path: "files/{{ lookup('community.general.random_string', special=false) }}"
      loop: "{{ files }}"
      register: out

and declare the files_map dictionary
  files_map: "{{ dict(out.results | json_query('[].[item, dest]')) }}"

gives, for example
  files_map:
    bar: files/roUAiHbU
    baz: files/jSArEgll
    foo: files/1V3M1wf7

Create the content. For example, for testing
    - copy:
        dest: "{{ item.value }}"
        content: |
          # file {{ item.key }}
      loop: "{{ files_map | dict2items }}"

and put the variable files_map into the group_vars/all/files_map
    - copy:
        dest: group_vars/all/files_map
        content: |
          files_map:
            {{ files_map | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) | indent(2) }}

Encrypt files/* and group_vars/all/files_map


Example of a complete playbook for testing
shell> cat create.yml 
- name: Create encrypted files
  hosts: localhost

  vars:

    files: [foo, bar, baz]
    files_map: "{{ dict(out.results | json_query('[].[item, dest]')) }}"

  tasks:

    - file:
        state: touch
        path: "files/{{ lookup('community.general.random_string', special=false) }}"
      loop: "{{ files }}"
      register: out

    - debug:
        var: files_map

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ item.value }}"
        content: |
          # file {{ item.key }}
      loop: "{{ files_map | dict2items }}"

    - copy:
        dest: group_vars/all/files_map
        content: |
          files_map:
            {{ files_map | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) | indent(2) }}



Use the dictionary files_map to access the files. For example, the play
- name: Use encrypted files
  hosts: localhost

  vars:

    files: [foo, bar, baz]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('file', files_map[item]) }}"
      loop: "{{ files }}"

gives abridged
ok: [localhost] => (item=foo) => 
  msg: '# file foo'
ok: [localhost] => (item=bar) => 
  msg: '# file bar'
ok: [localhost] => (item=baz) => 
  msg: '# file baz'

